# Existence of a hypersurface intersecting a given projective hypersurface transversally

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Given a hypersurface $X\in\mathbb CP^n$, can we always find a hypersurface $H\subset \mathbb CP^n$, s.t. $H$ and $X$ are transversal. Here the transversal I mean for every $x\in X\cap H$ we have that $T_xX+ T_xH=T_x\mathbb CP^n$, where these tangent spaces are holomorphic tangent spaces.

I am thinking of using Bertini's theorem, which gives at least one hyperplane $H\subset \mathbb CP^n$, s.t. $H\cap X$ is smooth, but can we guarantee $X,H$ are transversal?

Comment: Hint: this is just linear algebra. Can you write down the relation between the vector spaces $T_p(X\cap H)$, $T_pX$, $T_pH$, and $T_pX+T_pH$ inside $T_p\Bbb CP^n$? (Note that your $\oplus$ should be a $+$.)

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, I have fixed the issue you mentioned. For your hint, I think I see for $n>2$, but when $n=2$, $T_p(X\cap H)=0$ and $T_pX,T_pH$ are both one dimensional, I don't see how to guarantee $T_pX+T_pH=T_p\mathbb CP^n$.

Comment: Whether $n>2$ or not shouldn't matter. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=V(f)$ and $H=V(g)$, then $X\cap H =V(f,g)$. On the affine patch where $x_0$ is nonvanishing, the Jacobian of $X$ is the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \end{pmatrix}$$ while the Jacobian of $H$ is the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} \end{pmatrix}$$ and the Jacobian of $X\cap H$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix}.$$

The condition that $X\cap H$ is smooth is that the rank of this matrix is 2 at every point in $X\cap H$. This means that the kernels of the Jacobian of $X$ and the Jacobian of $H$ can't be the same at any point. Since these kernels are $n-1$ dimensional, adding any vector outside them gives the full space. As the tangent space is the kernel of the Jacobian, we have the desired result.